# Type-level Shapeless : aggregating a HList type elements

Tags: scala, type-conversion, monads, shapeless

I want to fold a HList with this Monad but **at the type-level**

```
trait TypeMonad{

  type Append[A,B] = A with B

  type Identity = Any
}
```

Hence, the HList : "A :: B:: C :: HNil " would give the type " A with B with C with Any"

Quite easy to do if i had implemented HList :

```
sealed trait HList {
  type Fuse
}
final trait HCons[H,L<:HList] extends HList {
  type Fuse = H with L#Fuse
}
final trait HNil extends Hlist {
  type Fuse = Any
}
```

However I don't know how to have this functionality in the shapeless environment

**My use case is the following :**

I need to restrain implicit class use to certain class by constraining the valid parameters
For example :

```
trait Filter
trait IC1Filter extends Filter
trait IC2Filter extends Filter
(...)
implicit class IC1[T <: IC1Filter](val v : MyPrettyClass[T]){...}
implicit class IC2[T <: IC2Filter](val v : MyPrettyClass[T]){...}
(...)
```

for example, if I have

```
class MC extends MyClass[IC1Filter with IC3Filter with IC4Filter with Any]
```

MC must be parsed by implicit classes IC1 or IC3 or IC4 but not by IC2 or IC5

--

I use HList composed of "Filters" in order to dynamically define the T parameter. When the wanted HList is created, I require to agregate the HList component in order to produce parsable filters for the implicit classes

So I need for example :

```
 IC1FIlter :: IC3Filter :: IC4Filter :: HNil
```

to be transformed to

```
 IC1Filter with IC3Filter with IC4Filter with Any
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? `T with Nothing` is equivalent to `Nothing` for all `T`. `Any` would be more useful as an identity wrt intersection.

Comment: @Miles Sabin Thanks, you just solved on of the bug I had!
However I'm still not able to use it in your library that provides every other functionality I required. If I got it, i suppose that a foldleft would do the trick. However I didn't understand how to implement it at type level in shapeless.

Comment: If you update the question to reflect that and give an example of how you'd like to use the fold I'll try and put an implementation together for you.

Comment: @Miles Sabin indeed i should have updated directly sorry

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not clear what you're trying to do: do you want an intersection (A and B and C) or a union (A or B or C)?

Comment: @MilesSabin 'm not sure I'm understanding. I want "with" constructor... I have edited the question, I hope it is must clear