# How to test type equality at type-level in scala?

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-level-computation

I would like to do some type level programming.
Scala type macros are dead, and it seems that shapeless is unable to do what I want.
All my problems would be resolve if I can get the following code to work
(this code is borrowed from http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/ and http://michid.wordpress.com/2010/06/18/type-level-programming-equality/)
It shows the implementation of a HList that has a "type remove" operator.
The bug come from the "EQ" structure that test wether two type are equivalent in order to remove then or not.
It seems to always return false in my case. I think that it's because I'm using "aliases" (?) but i do not see how to overcome this difficulty.

```
class Root {

  def typed[T](t: => T) {}
}

trait BooleanCompute extends Root {

  trait BOOL {
    type OUT <: BOOL

    type SELECT[TrueAction <: Action, FalseAction <: Action, Action] <: Action
  }

  case class TRUE() extends BOOL {
    type OUT = TRUE

    type SELECT[TrueAction <: Action, FalseAction <: Action, Action] = TrueAction
  }

  case class FALSE() extends BOOL {
    type OUT = FALSE

    type SELECT[TrueAction <: Action, FalseAction <: Action, Action] = FalseAction
  }

}
object  BooleanCompute extends BooleanCompute

import BooleanCompute._

case class Equality[A]() {
  def check(x: A)(implicit t: TRUE) = t

  def check[B](x: B)(implicit f: FALSE) = f
}

object Equality {
  def witness[T] = null.asInstanceOf[T]

  implicit val t: TRUE = null
  implicit val f: FALSE = null
}

trait EQ[A, B] extends {

  import Equality._

  type OUT = out.type
  val out = Equality[A]() check witness[B]


  val test1 = Equality[List[Boolean]] check witness[List[Boolean]]
  implicitly[test1.OUT =:= TRUE]
  // Does not compile since tt is True
  //implicitly[test1.t =:= FALSE]

  val test2 = Equality[Nothing] check witness[AnyRef]
  // Does not compile since ft is False
  // implicitly[test2.t =:= TRUE]
  implicitly[test2.OUT =:= FALSE]
}

object HList extends Root {

  type :+:[H, T <: HList] = HCons[H, T]
  val :+: = HCons

  sealed trait HList {
    self: HList =>

    type SELECT[ConsAction <: Action, NilAction <: Action, Action] <: Action

    type Remove[A] <: HList
  }

  final case class HCons[Head, Tail <: HList](head: Head, tail: Tail) extends HList {
    self: HList =>

    type SELECT[ConsAction <: Action, NilAction <: Action, Action] = ConsAction

    type Remove[A] = SELECT[
      EQ[Head, A]#OUT#SELECT[Tail#Remove[A], Head :+: Tail#Remove[A], HList],
      HNil,
      HList]

    def :+:[T](v: T) = HCons(v, this)
  }

  sealed case class HNil() extends HList {
    type SELECT[ConsAction <: Action, NilAction <: Action, Action] = NilAction

    type Remove[A] = HNil

    def :+:[T](v: T) = HCons(v, this)
  }

}

object yo extends App {

  import HList._

  case class AA()
  case class BB()
  case class CC()
  case class DD()

  type YO =  AA :+: BB :+:CC :+: HNil
  type YoRemoved =  AA :+:  CC :+: HNil
  val a = AA() :+: CC() :+: HNil()

  typed[YoRemoved](a)
  typed[YO#Remove[BB]](a)
}
```

Comment: "Scala macros are dead" -- Say what?

Comment: How come they are dead?

Comment: Sorry *type* macros are dead, i wrote to quickly. It has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

What's the issue you're having with shapeless? The following works perfectly well,

```
scala> val yo = AA() :: BB() :: CC() :: HNil
yo: AA :: BB :: CC :: HNil = AA() :: BB() :: CC() :: HNil

scala> typed[YO](yo) // Compiles

scala> val yoRemoved = yo.filterNot[BB]
yoRemoved: AA :: CC :: HNil = AA() :: CC() :: HNil

scala> typed[YoRemoved](yoRemoved)  // Compiles
```

Comment: its my use case that can not be done in shapeless.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664593/type-level-shapeless-aggregating-a-hlist-type-elements